# How to redirect LPT1 to PDF printer or OneNote printer

Tags: windows-7, printer, network-printer, ms-dos, visual-foxpro

There is a very old foxpro DOS program, which print doc via LPT1 , now user want to have soft copy . So I shared the PDF printer and OneNote printer on my local machine, and tried to map LPT1 to them as below

PDF printer:

```
net use LPT1: \\{my machine name}\pdf
```

Printer "Send to OneNote 2013":

```
net use LPT1: \\{my machine name}\one
```

Both commands completed successfully, and I can see the task could be added to printer's queue by below command, but nothing actually printed

```
print /d:LPT1 result.txt
=> result.txt is currently being printed
```

Note: I also tried LPT2, LPT3 , but got same result

Answer (score 1):

There are sometimes problems redirecting LPT1 if a physical printer port
exists on the computer. If that's your case, you could try the following:

1. Disable LPT1 in the BIOS (if supported)
2. Direct the old DOS program to use LPT2 (if it accepts such parameters)
   and redirect LPT2 instead
3. Use the ancient command `MODE LPT1:=LPT2:` (probably too old to work in Windows 7) and redirect LPT2 instead

You could also try to run in a Command Prompt (cmd) as
Administrator the following :

```
net use lpt1: /delete
net use lpt1: \\{my machine name}\{pdf-printer} /persistent:yes
```

If nothing works for you, here are a couple of shareware products that
supposedly solve the problem (never tried them):
[DOS Printer](http://www.dsbglobal.com/dosprinter/), [Printfil](http://www.printfil.com/english.htm).

Comment: I also tried LPT2, LPT3 , but got same result , anyway , thanks for your reply, and I'll try the products that you shared

Answer (score 1):

The main problem isn’t redirection. Windows printer drivers can’t handle the ASCII data streams with embedded print codes as sent by a DOS program. A DOS printer will render the data stream to paper. For all other print tasks, you need an external DOS-to-Windows print processor program (more around, even freeware). Or vDos, though that is primary intended to run DOS applications in Windows 64-bit, like most Windows 10 distributions nowadays.

Comment: thanks, would you give some names of "DOS-to-Windows print processor program" ?

Comment: Besides vDos built-in print processor, you can use: DOSPRN, DOSPrinter, WinPrint, and more, just Google. Though those are essentially Epson-only, so your DOS program has to be set to print to an Epson printer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today; I found that if you are using the file's path without quotes `""`, it shows the `is currently being printed` message but nothing is actually printed. If the file's directory has blank spaces the command-line needs all of the file's path inside quotes `""`.